# SSH command without prompting the message for ssh key save or cancel options

Tags: linux, ssh, awk, sed, grep

Need ssh command to connect another linux box from a linux box and fetch a output of particular command but connection should be established forcibly without prompting any ssh key to save, cancel.

So far tried command to connect and fetch output but receiving prompt to save public ssh key

```
value=$(ssh -q -P $passwd $userid@$box "head -1 /users/SB1.txt")
```

Comment: `ssh` does not have an option for passing a password by argument or through standard input.  This is by design.  You can use key-pair authentication to easily do what you seek, or use a tool such as Ansible if for some reason keypairs are impermissible.

Comment: can you share the steps/command for key-pair authentication ?

Answer (score 4):

You are looking to disable "Host Key Verification" and you need the following SSH options:

```
StrictHostKeyChecking no
UserKnownHostsFile /dev/null
```

If adding them to the command (rather than your ssh config file) then use

```
-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null
```

after the `-q` in your example command.

Comment: Note that, obviously, this reduces security by not checking the host keys and it might generate a warning for each ssh connection telling you that it wasn't possible to find the known hosts file.

Comment: command will be like value=$(ssh -q -P -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null $passwd $userid@$box "head -1 /users/SB1.txt")   ?

Comment: It shouldn't generate a warning (because /dev/null does exist). But yes this runs the risk that an attacker might get you to run the command on their computer instead of your own.

Comment: @user8554534 Yes, except I don't know what the `-P` option is for. If you are trying to use it for a password then that is wrong as @DopeGhoti has said.

Comment: by using the ssh connectivity command like value=$(ssh -q -P $passwd $userid@$box "head -1 /users/SB1.txt") in a while loop then the loop executes only once. If the ssh command is removed and executed the while loop with some commands in it, then the loop executes mutiple times as much as values given as a input.  Does ssh connectivity command does not work in while loop ? since output is received only once and loop not done

Comment: running ssh -q -P $passwd $userid@$box "head -1 /users/SB1.txt separately works... Also i am getting output once correctly using value=$(ssh -q -P $passwd $userid@$box "head -1 /users/SB1.txt") but not mutiple times in a while loop

Comment: Post as a new question. There is no particular reason that `ssh` should not work in a while loop.

Comment: @user8554534+Mark: something in the form `listfoos | while read foo; do ssh using $foo; done` fails because the first `ssh` 'drains' the other foos from stdin leaving no more foos for the while loop; see #24260 #66154 #107800 and SO #3214512 #346445

Answer (score 2):

Prepare (once on your SSH client user and box): Create a key pair for public key authentication

```
ssh-keygen -N '' -t rsa -f ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

Prepare (manually/interactively, once per user/server): Setup public key authentication, and accept host key without asking (this will ask you for `$userid`'s password once):

```
ssh-copy-id -o "StrictHostKeyChecking = no" $userid@$box
```

Then run your remote command without any interaction:

```
value=$(ssh -o 'BatchMode = yes' $userid@$box "head -1 /users/SB1.txt")
```

Your SSH client already knows the server's SSH host key by now, since it was added when you ran `ssh-copy-id`.

Answer (score 1):

There are two parts to this.  To connect without a password prompt, assuming you want to use password authentication (as implied in your question), you should use the program sshpass.  That is available to install via the package manager in many/most linux distros.  From the manual page:

> sshpass  is  a utility designed for running ssh using the mode referred
> to as "keyboard-interactive" password authentication, but in
> non-interactive mode.

Of course setting up an ssh key is preferable, but it's not possible to get your public key to the remote system at first without using the ssh password unless you have a different secure channel to do that with.  Given you're going to need to use the password to put your key there, you might as well use the password to do the job if this is a one-off.

The second part is, you need to set an appropriate value for StrictHostKeyChecking to prevent a prompt to save the key if this is the first time.  Typically you could use StrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new.  Then ssh will automatically add new host keys to the user known hosts file without prompting.

So a typical command could be:

```
value=$(sshpass -p$passwd ssh -q -oStrictHostKeyChecking=accept-new $userid@$box "head -1 /users/SB1.txt")
```

Answer (score -1):

You should definitely ***not*** mess with hostkeys, that's a bad idea.

What you should do is utilize ssh-keygen(1) (see 'man ssh-keygen') and create a public and private key. Since you don't want a password prompt simply don't supply a password. You'll find the results in the .ssh directory of your home directory (~/.ssh).

Next: add the contents of ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub to the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file on the remote server (you'll probably need to make it yourself).

Finally: tell SSH (sshd) that users are allowed to authorize with remote keys. This could be a default setting, but I'm not fully sure about every Linux distribution out there. Look for the option PubkeyAuthentication and make sure it's enabled.

SO what is going to happen here: you'll still be authorizing yourself with a rather strong authentication (your external key, kept in ~/.ssh/id_rsa) but because you didn't provide a password none will be requested and it'll make the login procedure "instant".

However, without sacrificing any security (only originated from your machine because everyone who uses that specific account can log on to the remote server, but that should be obvious).

But once again: Messing with StrictHostKeyChecking is a **bad** idea, and totally unneeded.

Comment: Without disabling host key checking it will still prompt on first login "Do you want to connect?" which is what the asker has said he wishes to avoid. Adding authentication keypairs is probably also needed/desirable but is not what he asked about.

Comment: Well, we'll have to agree to disagree then. The OP literally asked for a connection "without prompting any ssh key to save" which could be open for interpretation but to me boils down to a seemingly log on without further prompting. And the way to do that is described in my comment.